# Error in custom eshell function (exit and close window)

Tags: debugging, eshell

I got the below function from [an article on howardism.org](http://www.howardism.org/Technical/Emacs/eshell-fun.html). Its purpose is to exit eshell and close the corresponding window.

```
;; GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.10) of 2019-08-29
(defun eshell/x ()
  (insert "exit")
  (eshell-send-input)
  (delete-window))

(setq debug-on-error t)
```

Looked pretty straightforward to me. But when I start `emacs -Q` (See above code block for version info), then evaluate the above code and type `x<RET>` in an eshell window. I get the following:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument integer-or-marker-p nil)
  eshell-lisp-command(eshell/x nil)
  eshell-plain-command("x" nil)
  eshell-named-command("x")
  (prog1 (eshell-named-command "x") (run-hooks (quote eshell-this-command-hook)))
  (condition-case err (prog1 (eshell-named-command "x") (run-hooks (quote eshell-this-command-hook))) ((debug error) (run-hooks (quote eshell-this-command-hook)) (eshell-errorn (error-message-string err)) (eshell-close-handles 1)))
  (condition-case-unless-debug err (prog1 (eshell-named-command "x") (run-hooks (quote eshell-this-command-hook))) (error (run-hooks (quote eshell-this-command-hook)) (eshell-errorn (error-message-string err)) (eshell-close-handles 1)))
  (eshell-condition-case err (prog1 (eshell-named-command "x") (run-hooks (quote eshell-this-command-hook))) (error (run-hooks (quote eshell-this-command-hook)) (eshell-errorn (error-message-string err)) (eshell-close-handles 1)))
  (let ((eshell-this-command-hook (quote (ignore)))) (eshell-condition-case err (prog1 (eshell-named-command "x") (run-hooks (quote eshell-this-command-hook))) (error (run-hooks (quote eshell-this-command-hook)) (eshell-errorn (error-message-string err)) (eshell-close-handles 1))))
  (eshell-trap-errors (eshell-named-command "x"))
  (progn (eshell-trap-errors (eshell-named-command "x")))
  (catch (quote top-level) (progn (eshell-trap-errors (eshell-named-command "x"))))
  (progn (run-hooks (quote eshell-pre-command-hook)) (catch (quote top-level) (progn (eshell-trap-errors (eshell-named-command "x")))) (run-hooks (quote eshell-post-command-hook)))
  (let ((eshell-current-handles (eshell-create-handles t (quote append))) eshell-current-subjob-p) (progn (run-hooks (quote eshell-pre-command-hook)) (catch (quote top-level) (progn (eshell-trap-errors (eshell-named-command "x")))) (run-hooks (quote eshell-post-command-hook))))
  (eshell-commands (progn (run-hooks (quote eshell-pre-command-hook)) (catch (quote top-level) (progn (eshell-trap-errors (eshell-named-command "x")))) (run-hooks (quote eshell-post-command-hook))))
  eval((eshell-commands (progn (run-hooks (quote eshell-pre-command-hook)) (catch (quote top-level) (progn (eshell-trap-errors (eshell-named-command "x")))) (run-hooks (quote eshell-post-command-hook)))))
  eshell-send-input(nil)
  funcall-interactively(eshell-send-input nil)
  call-interactively(eshell-send-input nil nil)
  command-execute(eshell-send-input)
```

Without debug-on-error the "Wrong type argument"-message ends up in the buffer I was working in when invoking eshell.
To add to my confusion, this only happens the first time I call `eshell/x`.
Stepping through the function with edebug suggests that the error occurs in neither of the functions called inside `eshell/x` as the debugger only starts after I stepped over the last function call. Also when changing the function to this

```
(defun eshell/x ()
  (insert "exit")
  (eshell-send-input)
  (delete-window)
  (message "done deleting window"))
```

The debugger only gets entered after "done deleting window" appeared in the echo area.

Now I don't know how to continue searching for the error. Can someone please help me identify the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the default settings of `eshell`, typing the word "exit" in the `*eshell*` buffer, followed by the enter key, causes Emacs to execute the function `eshell/exit`.  As such, the proposed approach set forth in the question above, i.e., by inserting the word "exit" and calling `eshell-send-input`, is probably not the best way to handle this.

So, let us start by examining the built-in function `eshell/exit`, which is essentially a one-liner.  To do that, we evaluate `(require 'eshell)` with something like `M-:` (aka `M-x eval-expression`) ; or, we could copy/paste the `(require 'eshell)` statement to a `*scratch*` buffer and place our cursor just after the closing parenthesis and type `C-x C-e`.  Then, we locate the function with `M-x find-function RET eshell/exit RET` -- it looks like this:

```lisp
(defun eshell/exit ()
  "Leave or kill the Eshell buffer, depending on `eshell-kill-on-exit'."
  (throw 'eshell-terminal t))
```

Since it is just a one-liner, why not create our own function by simply changing the function name, like so?:

```lisp
(defun eshell/x ()
  "Leave or kill the Eshell buffer, depending on `eshell-kill-on-exit'."
  (throw 'eshell-terminal t))
```

We decide to pay attention to the doc-string about the variable `eshell-kill-on-exit` and if we are curious, we type `C-h v` (aka `M-x describe-variable`) and look it up:

```
eshell-kill-on-exit is a variable defined in ‘esh-mode.el’.
Its value is t

Documentation:
If non-nil, kill the Eshell buffer on the ‘exit’ command.
Otherwise, the buffer will simply be buried.

You can customize this variable.
```

As luck would have it, we have the benefit of a similar thread which has an accepted answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51867693/emacs-eshell-kill-window-on-exit

So, we take the answer in that similar thread -- suggesting that we advise `eshell-life-is-too-much`, and we combine it with our new function `eshell/x`:

```lisp
(require 'eshell)

(defun eshell/x ()
  (throw 'eshell-terminal t))

(defun my-custom-func () 
  (when (not (one-window-p))
    (delete-window)))

(advice-add 'eshell-life-is-too-much :after 'my-custom-func)
```